# PHP shell_exec command

Tags: javascript, php, shell-exec

I am trying to implement a function with php which check whether user has svn or git installed in his computer. I am using shell_exec command of php. But it seems it works in server and not check user computer and not related with client side. Is there a possible way to implement this function or Should i try to check javascript for this option? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Indeed php code (all php code) will only work on server, not on client.

Javascript won't solve your problem as it is run inside a sandbox to prevent(!) access of local resources.

Comment: Is there any option or anyway to check it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do a check on a user's computer with a server side programming language on a server.

There is **no way** you can access the computer of a visiting user and run scripts on it in PHP.

If it is important to you to know if the user has either GIT or SVN installed, you could also just ask them to fill out a form, providing you with an answer.

Comment: Can I make this connection with ssh I mean try to connect user computer from server with ssh and run command in user computer after his permission.

Comment: I don't think you should access a user's computer at all. If you really want to run software on their computer, you're gonna have to have them download the software and run it. But I don't recommend you doing this before establishing what it is exactly you're trying to achieve.